# Google sheet custom function array return problem

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets custom function, is it possible / have any way to make 2-dimensional array return value editable?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question from `In google sheet custom function, is it possible / have any way to make 2 dimensional array return value editable ?`. In order to correctly understand your question, can I ask you about the detail of it? Can you provide the sample input and output situations as the image?

Comment: function test (a,b){ let c=[a,b]; return[c];}  input cell a1=8, b1=3, output cell: d1=8,e1=3; function was call from cell d1, if i change value from the e1 than it show REF error, how  i can i remove this error and can edit e1 cell

Comment: That's because you're calling the custom function and you're trying to overwrite the data by inputting in cell where that function will return the value, that's what causing the `#Ref `error. If that is your end goal, i would advice you to use button or edit trigger, because that way function will paste the value in those cells, that will allow you to edit them later.

Comment: That's mean I need make individual script with trigers for individual cell if I want to achive the cell editing charecteristics

Comment: No, just to be clear you want to copy value from cells `A1:B1`to paste it to cell `D1:E1` right?

Comment: Actually i want a custom function that is -The function would fill an adjacent cell in the next column with the value of a target cell(a1,f2,g3 any cell) if the adjacent cell in the next column is blank. If the adjacent cell in the next column is not blank, then the function should ignore the adjacent cell.

Comment: not same rang, a1 and b1 are two different range

Comment: Ya that  can be done using custom function but problem is, if you try to overwrite the values you're getting return from custom function, in any case it will cause `Ref` error

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that the discussions have already been advanced. In this case, I would like to respect the existing discussions.